# Running code in a app from a different app

Tags: android

Say I am developing two apps 'A' & 'B'. 'A' contains a function/code 'f' to perform any task. If I am firing an implicit intent in 'A' to open an app 'B',  is there a way that I can run  'f' over/in the 'B'?
(Note: API of 'B' is not available)

If yes, how  it will be implemented?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can multiple Android applications share a single process and application context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664090/can-multiple-android-applications-share-a-single-process-and-application-context)

Comment: Short answer, yes, you can. It's not a very good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK what you're trying to perform isn't possible due to obvious security issues, but I'm currently trying to do the same, see [Intent Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), maybe there is something to do with it...

Otherwise you could use adb commands from your app A to start your app B and design the activity to make it run your "f" method on Activity start

Answer (score 0):

You application that will perform function should declare in Android Manifest a custom Intent filter and the application can open it with this custom filter. Check this
[Start Activity Using Custom Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921451/start-activity-using-custom-action)