# Start different application inside my app (container)

Tags: android, android-intent, containers

How to run a different application inside my own one. When I start activity I want to show it inside my application and replace my container activity with activity from different application (but on `recent tasks` is still should be shown as "Container App"

```
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent         intent  = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    context.finishAffinity();
```

This open new task in my `recent tasks` tab. But how to remain in the same task?

Comment: Fragment is the way to go here

Comment: As I far as I know, this is not possible.

Comment: @AHoneyBustard May you explain your approach with fragments? I'd like to know about it please.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @AHoneyBustard Is this a joke lol. The question is about running an external app within your app.

Comment: Not a joke but a suggestion of how he can achieve what he wants. I quote 'different application(activity)'. One could say he wants two activities on the same screen. Thats when Fragments come in handy, to at least optically achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the concept of "application" in Android is slightly an extended one.

An application - technically a process - can have multiple activities, services, content providers and/or broadcast listeners. If at least one of them is running, the application is up and running (the process).

So, what you have to identify is how do you want to "start the application".

Ok... here's what you can try out:

Create an intent with action=MAIN and category=LAUNCHER
Get the PackageManager from the current context using context.getPackageManager
packageManager.queryIntentActivity(, 0) where intent has category=LAUNCHER, action=MAIN or packageManager.resolveActivity(, 0) to get the first activity with main/launcher
Get theActivityInfo you're interested in
From the ActivityInfo, get the packageName and name
Finally, create another intent with with category=LAUNCHER, action=MAIN, componentName = new ComponentName(packageName, name) and setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
Finally, context.startActivity(newIntent)

Answer (score 0):

> **This is not possible.**

Every application runs in its own process. However you can make multiple applications to run in same process if you assign same values to `android:shareUserID` and `android:process` in both applications and sign them with same certifcate.

[Can multiple Android applications share a single process and application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664090/can-multiple-android-applications-share-a-single-process-and-application-context)

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42129/why-each-android-application-runs-on-a-different-dalvik-vm-process