# In which process are Android Instrumentation Tests run on?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm newly exploring the Android Espresso testing framework.
It seems Android creates a test apk that is separate from the application apk. This test apk contains all the tests. (actions, verifications).
My question is, in which process does this test run? My guess is that it runs on the same process as the application apk (since it needs to access the application context), but I can't find anything on the web confirming this. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: You can find out by running those tests in a debugger and putting a breakpoint in the test and code under test.  You should be able to find the process number that way for each.  That or put in something that logs those numbers for each

Answer (score 1):

From possum's suggestion, I logged the processname and pid in both my app apk and test apk. Turns out they live in the same process, as I suspected.
I didn't know multiple apk's can live in the same process, but it seems to be possible, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17664090).